# Creating Dynamic playlist using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, media-library

I have a playlist script in my wordpress theme that puts the URL from a file in the media gallery into a playlist script that can be read by the audio player.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myPlaylist = [
 <?php
 foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
 {
   echo "{
        mp3:'".$file->guid."',
        title:'".$file->post_title."',
        artist:'"."',
        rating:5,
        buy:'".$file->post_excerpt."',
        price:'"."',
        duration:'"."',
        cover:'"."'
    },"
; }
?>
];
</script>
```

My problem is that I need to figure out how to change the output of the php script on the LAST item, so that there is no comma after the "}". I've been told this is an AJAX problem, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing objects from PHP to JS, the safest, simplest way is to use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). This way you won't have to worry about breaking your JS syntax in case `$file->post_title` contains `'` or any other character that would break it.

```
<?php
 $playlist = array();
 foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
 {
   $playlist[] = array(
        'mp3'=>$file->guid,
        'title'=>$file->post_title,
        'artist'=>'',
        'rating'=>5,
        'buy'=>$file->post_excerpt,
        'price'=>'',
        'duration'=>'',
        'cover'=>''
    );
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var myPlaylist = <?= json_encode($playlist) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: You are one bad-a** mofo! Thanks for this. Didn't know about json_enconde. Super cool :). The music player works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one:

```
<?php
 $playlist = array();
 foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
 {
   $playlist[] = "{
        mp3:'".$file->guid."',
        title:'".$file->post_title."',
        artist:'"."',
        rating:5,
        buy:'".$file->post_excerpt."',
        price:'"."',
        duration:'"."',
        cover:'"."'
    }";
 }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myPlaylist = [
 <?php echo implode(',' $playlist);?>
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$audiofiles` is associative array, have you tried this:

```
<?php
 $totalFiles = count($audiofiless);
 $i = 0;
 foreach ($audiofiles as $file)
 {
   echo "{
        mp3:'".$file->guid."',
        title:'".$file->post_title."',
        artist:'"."',
        rating:5,
        buy:'".$file->post_excerpt."',
        price:'"."',
        duration:'"."',
        cover:'"."'
    }" . (++$i < $totalFiles ? ',' : '');
; }
?>
```

However, if it's not an associative then it even simplier since you don't have to increment anything and you can use ordinary `for` cycle...

Answer (score 0):

You could change the foreach to a for and do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myPlaylist = [
 <?php
 for ($i=0; $i<=$audiofile.length; $i++)
 {
   $file = $audiofile[$i];
   echo "{
        mp3:'".$file->guid."',
        title:'".$file->post_title."',
        artist:'"."',
        rating:5,
        buy:'".$file->post_excerpt."',
        price:'"."',
        duration:'"."',
        cover:'"."'
    }"
    if ($i<$audiofile.length)
    {
      echo ","
    }
; }
?>
];
</script>
```